# Wordpress + GIT + MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, git, git-merge

Несколько разработчиков используют GIT в работе с сайтом, который сделан на WordPress.

Проблем с базой данных. Как её можно мерджить? Может есть решение или мысли по этому?

Comment: А зачем мержить БД? Это же куча информации, которая будет каждый раз сохраняться. На GitHub можно, конечно, но я не вижу смысла, слишком быстро будет увеличиваться репозиторий. Могу предложить: залить ее на отдельный сервер и всем обращаться.

Comment: Базу данных вообще нельзя под контроль версий. Можно только версионировать скрипты для её создания, миграций и т.п.

Comment: Всем обращаться к ней нельзя. Кто-то свои тесты делает и могу испортить БД. Поэтому и нужно как-то её уже на PROD-е мержить.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). Это программа позволяет описывать изменения БД в различных форматах (XML, YAML, JSON и SQL) и применять их в правильной последовательности. Она следит за тем, какие изменения были применены, а какие нет. Позволяет откатывать изменения и применять их снова. Так как изменения хранятся в текстовых файлах, то их можно (и нужно) помести в систему контроля версий.